# Remove a non existing postgres cluster

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-10.04

I have a postgres 8.4 install on ubuntu 10.04.
I created a cluster on a disk that is not mountable anymore. Now I want to remove postgres  but when I do `apt-get remove postgresql-8.4` I get:

```
dpkg: error processing postgresql-8.4 (--remove):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-8.4
```

And when I do a `apt-get upgrade` is says:

```
Selecting previously deselected package postgresql-8.4.
Preparing to replace postgresql-8.4 8.4.9-0ubuntu0.10.04 (using .../postgresql-8.4_8.4.14-0ubuntu10.04_amd64.deb) ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 8.4 database server
 * Error: /mnt/db/postgresql/8.4/main is not accessible or does not exist
   ...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql-8.4, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 8.4 database server
 * Error: /mnt/db/postgresql/8.4/main is not accessible or does not exist
   ...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql-8.4, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-8.4_8.4.14-0ubuntu10.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
 * Starting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server
 * Error: /mnt/db/postgresql/8.4/main is not accessible or does not exist
   ...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql-8.4, action "start" failed.
```

It looks like apt is choking on the non existing cluster. How can I remove that cluster and deinstall postgres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it:

```
pg_dropcluster --stop 8.4 main
>>> warning: corrupted cluster: data directory does not exist
```

Ignore this warning. If you do it a second time it says that the cluster is gone.

To get dpkg in a decent state again:

```
apt-get install postgres-8.4
```

And get rid of it:

```
apt-get remove --purge postgres-8.4
apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: FYI, this is *not* a Postgres problem -- It's brokenness in the Ubuntu/Debian `apt` package management tool...

Comment: Never said it was postgres's fault. apt-get remove should just ignore errors from stopping an process that didn't run in the first place.

Comment: True, but you neglected to include the appropriate tag for the component that should be blamed ([tag:ubuntu-10.04]). Tags are important around here :)

Comment: Hence your name :)